# Move form select options outside of current html file?

Tags: html, forms, select

Is there a way to move the options for a form select box outside of the html file?

I am setting up a form select for "country" and if I list every country as an option in my html doc it takes up a ton of lines and is annoying while I am still editing the document.

```
<form>
  <select name="country"> <option>[list of countries here]</option> </select>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can load them dynamically using AJAX and PHP/MySQL for example to populate them from a database. Example tutorial here: http://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-and-ajax/

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using the Redesigned Country Selector jQuery plugin, you can find it [here](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector).

All you need is to include jquery script files along with any autocomplete plugin you wish (if you don't like the one they already provide). Just scroll down and select the "Documentation" tab for an easy explanation of how to integrate it into your code.

EDIT: Actually, just noticed that the redesigned country selector still lists all country options in the html file. As i am a user of the bootstrap framework, i suggest you use [Bootstrap Form Helpers](http://vincentlamanna.com/BootstrapFormHelpers/country.html). Look up the Countries plugin, it even shows the flags for each country! If you don't want to use bootstrap, look up `bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.en_US.js` and the corresponding `bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.js`. Then, read the code to see how the original author linked the javascript variable containing the list of all countries to an html class.

Answer (score 0):

You could also list the option tags in one really long line.  It would make editing the option tags hard, but your file would be more easily readable.